# How to find the value of a trigonometric expression using python?

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, simpy

I've multiplied 6 4x4 matrices using python Simpy and the output for the first element after running the code is:

*−1.545(−sin(60)cos(80)cos(90)+sin(80)cos(60))sin(90)+0.815cos(60)+1.2sin(60)sin(80)cos(90)+0.158((−(−sin(60)cos(80)cos(90)+sin(80)cos(60))sin(90)+(sin(60)sin(80)cos(90)+cos(60)cos(80))cos(90))cos(200)+(sin(60)sin
2
(90)+(sin(60)sin(80)cos(90)+cos(60)cos(80))sin(90)cos(90)+(−sin(60)cos(80)cos(90)+sin(80)cos(60))cos
2
(90))sin(200))cos(100)+0.158(((−sin(60)cos(80)cos(90)+sin(80)cos(60))sin(90)cos(90)−sin(60)sin(90)cos(90)+(sin(60)sin(80)cos(90)+cos(60)cos(80))sin
2
(90))sin(90)+(sin(60)sin
2
(90)+(sin(60)sin(80)cos(90)+cos(60)cos(80))sin(90)cos(90)+(−sin(60)cos(80)cos(90)+sin(80)cos(60))cos
2
(90))cos(90)cos(200)−(−(−sin(60)cos(80)cos(90)+sin(80)cos(60))sin(90)+(sin(60)sin(80)cos(90)+cos(60)cos(80))cos(90))sin(200)cos(90))sin(100)+1.545(sin(60)sin(80)cos(90)+cos(60)cos(80))cos(90)+1.2cos(60)cos(80)*

Is there a way to find the solution to this expression using python?

Comment: it would have been easier if you could add operators between expressions. also between expressions and literals of course.

Comment: @BedirYilmaz this is the output of the first element of a 4x4 transformation matrix obtained after matrix multiplication. how can I add operators there? is it possible?

Comment: I mean multiplication operators such as *

Comment: Or, if you are multiplying just 6 matrices, just use numpy rather than simpy?

Comment: @jtlz2 this is my matrix--> Matrix([
[cos(theta1), -sin(theta1)*cos(90), -sin(90)*sin(theta1), 0.815*cos(theta1)],
[sin(theta1),  cos(90)*cos(theta1),  sin(90)*cos(theta1), 0.815*sin(theta1)],
[          0,             -sin(90),              cos(90),                 0],
[          0,                    0,                    0,                 1]]) Can I use NumPy in these kinds of matrices?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import all the trigonometric functions used in the expression.

```
from math import sin,cos
```

Then you need to convert each degree parameter to radians so that it can be used with standard python functions.

```
from math import radians
# example
cos(radians(60))
sin(radians(80))
```

After the conversion is finished, you can finally add the multiplication operators

```
# to change this
-1.545sin(60)cos(80)cos(90)

# into this
-1.545 * sin(radians(60)) * cos(radians(80)) * cos(radians(90))
```

Modify the whole trigonometric expression that you have based on the rules above and then you are good to go. Your code is ready to be run as a python file.